# Magento 2: Which observer event is used instead of "core_block_abstract_to_html_after" in Magento 1?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I use the "core_block_abstract_to_html_after" event in magento 1. What is the equivalent in Magento 2?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock::toHtml` haven't such event. You can achieve such result in different ways:

1. If you need to add some customization for specific block, you can
   use it's *_afterToHtml* method.
2. To customize all block's output globally, use plugin for
   *Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock* and implement *aftreToHtml* method. More information available here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: i add afterToHtml method using plugin. it's showing blank page if i return $html i show following error Interceptor could not be converted to string i use this interceptor in my di.xml Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock

Comment: @Pratik, Try to clean var/generation folder. Here is code snippet, which worked for me:
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockInterface">
        <plugin name="block.plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Model\BlockPlugin" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
In Vendor\Module\Model\BlockPlugin I implemented such method:
    public function afterToHtml($subject, $result)
    {
        return "<b>" . $result . "</b>";
    }

Comment: yes you r right Thx for help :)

Answer (score 0):

_afterToHtml is a protected function, plugin only works with public functions.
There is a similar event of m1 that you can use in replacement of old 'core_block_abstract_to_html_after', for m2: 'view_block_abstract_to_html_after'.